# How do butterflies defend themselves from other creatures when they don't have the ability to sting or some other offensive/defensive mechanism?

Tags: entomology

How do butterflies defend themselves from other creatures when they don't have the ability to sting or some other offensive/defensive mechanism?

> Butterflies are part of the class of Insects in the order Lepidoptera. Adult butterflies have large, often brightly coloured wings, and conspicuous, fluttering flight.

Comment: Hi there, I downvoted your question because its important to include an attempt at an answer in your question. Hopefully @fileunderwater gave you the answer you were looking for :)

Comment: It might come across harsh @ShyamRadhakrishnan especially as a new user, but you'll get used to it and eventually understand why!

Answer (score 6):

Butterflies have a number of defence mechanisms, even if they don't have the ability to sting (as adults - see spines in larvae below). Here is a non-comprehensive list of some defensive mechanisms:

- Toxins or repellents, which can be present in both adults and larvae.
- [Aposematism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposematism) (warning coloration)
- [Mimicry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimicry), both in the form of resembling other poisonous species and using features such as eyespots.
- Spines, bristles or long hairs, often in larvae (see [google images](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=caterpillar+spines&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=aIzUVMjDHqOdygOf2YH4Bw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1600&bih=773)), to make ingestion highly unpleasent or dangerous. See the [Pine processionary moth (*Thaumetopoea pityocampa*)](http://www.forestry.gov.uk/pineprocessionarymoth) for an nice example of defensive larval hairs.
- Camouflage/hiding
- Sound clicks used to startle or disorient predators. This is most often known from moths to prevent bat attacks (see e.g. [*Cycnia tenera*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycnia_tenera) and [Fullard et al, 1994](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/194/1/285.full.pdf)).
- Conspicuous features at the edge of wings to make them targets of attack, e.g. eyespots or appendages, which are used to lure predators to attack non-essential body parts (see [Olofsson et al, 2013](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/bij.12063/abstract) for an example).

Comment: Nice answer! I removed my comment from the question as this says it all. +1